# Warning MSB3270 in Fakes projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, warnings, microsoft-fakes

After migration to VS2012 (Update 2) and using Fakes, MSBuild began to show a new warning:

**There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "System.Data", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.**

All projects in our solution are configured to "AnyCPU" Platform Target. But dynamically generated Fakes projects contain a reference to System.Data with next path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
So, how to configure Fakes to use System.Data.dll from GAC_64 instead of GAC_32?

Previously I asked this question on MS forum, but without any suitable result http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/185e8de7-e43f-4034-bfdc-01762b2bd0ba/#7d61159f-217a-4b4b-8aa1-bacae64e473f

Comment: Please submit this as a bug at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio